# Chosing a row with a null value cell

Tags: sql-server, null, row

I have a table like that

```
Bookid   StuId        borrowdate    ReturnedDate
2        10           2013-05-01    2013-05-31
2        10           2013-06-01    NULL
```

NULL value mean the book isn't returned. I want to chose the 2nd row and i try this on sql server

```
CREATE PROC validate(
    @stuid varchar(50), 
    @bookid int,
    @returndate date)
AS    
SELECT * FROM Borrow
    WHERE StuID = @stuid
        AND BookID = @bookid
        AND ReturnedDate = @returndate
    go
```

but the result is a null table. Anyone can help me, thanks !

Comment: `and ReturnedDate is null`, as any rudimentary SQL documentation (or Google search) will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you can't test if something is equal to NULL - it's not a valid test.

So if you want to find books that have not returned, you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM Borrow
    WHERE StuID = @stuid
        AND BookID = @bookid
        AND ReturnedDate IS NULL;
```

Or if you need to use a parameter that may be null, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Borrow
    WHERE StuID = @stuid
        AND BookID = @bookid
        AND ISNULL(ReturnedDate, '2008-11-11') = ISNULL (@returndate, '2008-11-11');
```

Note that the `IS NULL` in the first is a different beast to `ISNULL(` in the second.

The first, `IS NULL` returns true if the field is null.

The second says "if the field is null, use this value instead".

The dates are standard SQL date format, and this relies on choosing a magic date that no one can ever return a book on (e.g. 50 years before the library was created).